# print concat value of newline("\n") result shows as <?> symbol in C

Tags: c

I have a code below

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char *price_c = "200";
    char *s_att = "test ";

    int satt=strlen(s_att);
    int price_len = strlen(price_c);

    int send_attach_len = price_len+satt;

    size_t length = send_attach_len +2;
    char *concat = malloc(sizeof(char) *length);

    snprintf(concat, length, "%s%s%s", s_att, price_c, "\n");
    printf("value of concat is %s", concat);
}
```

when I see the value printed, I have only `test 200` , but on some other occasion, I have `test 200 < ? >` where `< ? >` is a weird symbol, somehow the new line is not recognised.
But it is very strange because not all the time this weird symbol is shown up.. 
It just came up randomly. I am using `ubuntu 10.04`

Can anyone help me to solve this new line problem, so that it shows new line, and not weird symbol. Or maybe I can change the approach to concat the above value so that the new line is rendered correctly, and not showing a weird symbol?

Comment: It works correctly. I think your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @xanatos : yes, it works correctly. but sometimes it shows me an additional weird symbol after the 200 (and not new line)

Comment: @Mahesh No, he is printing an additional `\n` at the end of the string.

Comment: @Mahesh : thank you for the size thing. but I think that the "\n" is not recognised as ENTER in the console. it is instead rendered as other weird symbol..

Comment: Always assume heap corruption when you have problems like this.  Plenty of room for it, I doubt we're looking at the real code.

Comment: @Xanatos : for "\n" that is a string, it is intepreted as new line isn't it, and in sprintf I should specify as %s ? but this is strange, as I do not get a new line (as if no enter shown)

Comment: @heike It's as said by Mat. The problem is in the `#include` (the part about `main` is a problem but isn't causing this bug). Try this code: http://www.ideone.com/TAaQz

Answer (score 0):

The code looks ok, except for the very important fact that you are missing some headers.

`strlen` is in `<string.h>`, and `malloc` is in `<stdlib.h>`.

Include those, turn on your compiler warnings (`-Wall` for GCC), change your `main` signature to:

```
int main(void) { }
```

and actually return an int from it (or compile as C99, `std=c99` for GCC), and the problems should go away.